# jq- reference current position in loop

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I have a log file called `log.json` that's formatted like this:

```
{"msg": "Service starting up!"}  
{"msg": "Running a job!"}
{"msg": "Error detected!"}
```

And another file called `messages.json`, which looks like this:

```
{"msg": "Service starting up!", "out": "The service has started"}
{"msg": "Error detected!", "out": "Uh oh, there was an error!"}
{"msg": "Service stopped", "out": "The service has stopped"}
```

I'm trying to write a function using `jq` that reads in both files, and whenever it finds a `msg` in `log.json` that matches a `msg` in `messages.json`, print the value of `out` in the corresponding line in `messages.json`. So, in this case, I'm hoping to get this as output:

```
"The service has started"
"Uh oh, there was an error!"
```

The closest that I've been able to get so far is the following:

```
jq --argfile a log.json --argfile b messages.json -n 'if ($a[].msg == $b[].msg) then $b[].out else empty end'
```

This successfully performs all of the comparisons that I'm hoping to make. However, rather than printing the specific `out` that I'm looking for, it instead prints every `out` whenever the if statement returns true (which makes sense. `$b[].out` was never redefined, and asks for each of them). So, this statement outputs:

```
"The service has started"
"Uh oh, there was an error!"
"The service has stopped"
"The service has started"
"Uh oh, there was an error!"
"The service has stopped"
```

So at this point, I need some way to ask for `$b[current_index].out`, and just print that. Is there a way for me to do this (or an entirely seperate approach that I can use)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

messages.json effectively defines a dictionary, so let's begin by creating a JSON dictionary which we can lookup easily. This can be done conveniently using INDEX/2 which (in case your jq does not have it) is defined as follows:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({};
    .[$row|idx_expr|
      if type != "string" then tojson
      else .
      end] |= $row);
```

A first-cut solution is now straightforward:

```
INDEX($messages[]; .msg) as $dict
| inputs
| $dict[.msg]
| .out
```

Assuming this is in program.jq, an appropriate invocation would be as follows (note especially the `-n` option):

```
jq -n --slurpfile messages messages.json -f program.jq log.json
```

The above will print `null` if the `.msg` in the log file is not in the dictionary. To filter out these nulls, you could (for example) add `select(.)` to the pipeline.

Another possibility would be to use the original `.msg`, as in this variation:

```
INDEX($messages[]; .msg) as $dict
| inputs
| . as $in
| $dict[.msg]
| .out // $in.msg
```